# Relative or object clause: "that knowledge of the truth takes flight as if by magic"

Tags: clauses

> *To be critical meant to raise thought so far above all constraints **that, through the perception of the falseness of constraints, knowledge of the truth takes flight as if by magic.***

I would like to ask whether you think that the clause "that, through the perception of the falseness of constraints, knowledge of the truth takes flight as if by magic" is a relative or object one.

Comment: Hi, @bartleby Sorry, just in case you didn't see my update, my post should have said *indirect Complement* not *indirect object*. By the way you may want to wait a day or two because you may get other useful answers to your interesting question, but poeple may not bother to write an answer for you if you've already selected one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To be critical meant to raise thought so far above all constraints [that, through the perception of the falseness of constraints, knowledge of the truth takes flight as if by magic].

The clause in brackets is not an object clause or a relative clause. It is a content clause licensed by the deictic degree adverb *so*. Because *so* is part of the adjective phrase *so far* we say that it is the indirect Complement of the adjective *far*. It might be easier to see how it works if we have a simpler sentence:

- It was so big [that we couldn't carry it].

Clauses like this licensed by degree adverbs such as *so* tell us of some sort of result which explains exactly how 'X', in this case how *big* something is.

Comment: So, in "I'm so hungry I could eat a horse", the clause *I could eat a horse* is the indirect object of *hungry*?

Comment: @TRomano Sorry, that was a slip! No, it's the indirect *Complement* of *far* in the OQ and the indirect *Complement* of hungry in your example.